# Target field on Windows shortcut is disabled

Tags: windows, shortcuts

A number of applications on my system have **working** desktop shortcuts which have the "Target" value disabled. This makes it impossible to modify. The value in the disabled textbox is the name of the application, not a path to the file I'm expecting to run.

Is there a way to re-enable this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These shortcuts are special. The target of these shortcuts is not a file path or folder. It is registered in the system application (simplifying). Say, they link to [PIDLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090(v=vs.85).aspx#ID_Lists_PIDL), not files.

The answer is - you can't reenable the target field. You may only recreate shortcuts (or modify them programmatically, not sure).

Comment: You could also try opening the `.lnk` in Notepad++.

Answer (score 4):

However, you can

- Start the application with the shortcut.
- Open Task Manager.
- Find the just started app (by name).
- Right click on it and Open file location.

Now you can make customized shortcuts based on the same application.

I know this isn't a perfect solution but might be adequate.

Comment: This will only work for PIDLs that map to exe files (not all of them do).